# How to resolve @Value with resources in testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, junit

I have the following service:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Service {

    @Value("${filename}")
    private String filename;

    private final Repository repository;

}
```

And I'm trying to test it, for which I'd like to resolve `filename` with a specific value from `application-test.yml`:

```
filename: a beautiful name
```

So far, my test is the following:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ServiceTest {

    @Value("${filename}")
    private String filename;

    @Mock
    private Repository repository;

    @InjectMocks
    private Service service;

}
```

What can I do to initialize `filename` correctly?

Comment: ... why would that need to be dynamic?

Comment: well, I does not need to be, but anyway I need to inject the property into the service...

Comment: meaning it is dynamic. Why do you need that, that is the question.

Comment: Well, the name will depend on the execution environment...

Comment: it's a unit test. even if it were an integration test, why would you execute this on different execution environments? please don't tell me you execute tests on your production environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using Mockito, Spring isn't really involved in bootstrapping your test so things like `@Value` or `application-test.yml` mean nothing.

The best solution is to add the `filename` property in `Service` to your constructor (like `repository`):

```java
@Service
public class Service {
    private final String filename;
    private final Repository repository;

    // Now you don't need @RequiredArgConstructor
    public Service(@Value("${filename}") String filename, Repository repository) {
        this.filename = filename;
        this.repository.repository;
    }
}
```

This allows you to inject any value you want by calling the constructor in your test:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private Repository repository;

    private Service service;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        // Now you don't need @InjectMocks
        this.service = new Service("my beautiful name", repository);
    }
}
```